# Communicate with other component by sending object from parent to the child

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to get used to with component communication but still having some problems with syntax - got confused a bit. Each language have their own communication system and learning new one is not hard, but the syntax makes eveyrthing different.

I would like to communicate with child. The parent is a `Shop.vue` and the child is a `ShoppingCart.vue`. Every time we add something to our shopping cart it is going to go through the shop, right ? Basically shop should have all of the products and to keep it readable and clean the best aprouch would be migrate part of the code which is responsible for shopping cart to it's own file.

**ShoppingCart.vue**

```
<template>
    <!-- Basically on click we would like to add new product to the shopping cart -->
    <button @click="addProductToShoppingCart()">
        <img src="../assets/shoppingcart.png" alt="25">
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                cartProducts: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            // It's kinda should take as an argument product which we have to add to the cart
            addProductToShoppingCart (product) {
                this.cartProducts.push(product)
                // And here I have a question, what would be second argument ? I don't think it's going to be 'product'
                this.$emit('addProductToShoppingCart', product)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Shop.vue**

```
<template>
    <!-- product going to ref to preselected product in the shop so it will not be a null -->
    <shopping-cart @addToShoppingCart="addToShoppingCart(product)">
    </shopping-cart>
</template>

<script>
    import ShoppingCart from './ShoppingCart'

    export default {
        name: 'shop',
        data () {
            return {
                // The list won't be empty, I've deleted all of boilerplate code
                products: [],
            }
        },
        components: {
            'shopping-cart': ShoppingCart
        },
        methods: {

            addToShoppingCart (product) {
               // Do we need the same method here? 
            },

        }
    }
</script>
```

Could any one give me some advices how could I modifie the current code to achieve my goal ?

Comment: the functionality is same as the **todo list**, there are about 50 tutorials on that. here's just one that uses components https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-to-do-app-with-vue-js-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically understood how to use the emit flow to communicate between child and parent component.

But in your ShopingCart.vue component there's a problem.
You need to pass an argument into your addProductToShoppingCart directive inside your button, because it will be used inside your methods.

If not, your method addProductToShoppingCart() is adding nothing into the products array.

So first, i added a product object that contains all your product properties.

Then, i pass as an argument the product object inside your addProductToShoppingCart(product) method.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
    <img :src="product.img">
    <button @click="addProductToShoppingCart(product)">
    </button>
  </div>

  <script>

  export default {
    data() {
        return: {
            product: {
                name: 'test',
                img: require('../assets/shoppingcart.png')
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // your method
        addProductToShoppingCart (product) {
          this.$emit('addProductToShoppingCart', product)
        }
    }
  }
  </script>
</template>
```

Then inside your Shop.vue you have to modify your method with this:

```
addToShoppingCart (product) {
   // Do we need the same method here? 
   this.products.push(product);
 },
```

Comment: I think you've missunderstood me. I don't want to populate a product list in `Shop.vue` but I want to create a new list inside `ShoppingCart.vue` and then push a selected product in `Shop.vue` to list inside `ShoppingCart.vue`

Comment: My bad so.
If i understood your problem, you should push the product object inside your cartProducts array, as you did before. And then in your Shop component push the product object inside your products array.